# Simulate all physical buttons like the pressure on the home button on iOS 7 (Jailbreak)

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

I'm trying to simulate the "home button pressed" on iOS 7 but the previous method used on iOS 6 doesn't work. I speak of course of a jailbroken device.

```
#include "GSEvent.h"

    - (void)simulateHomeButton
    {
       struct GSEventRecord record;
       memset(&record, 0, sizeof(record));
       record.type = kGSEventMenuButtonDown;
       record.timestamp = GSCurrentEventTimestamp();
       GSSendSystemEvent(&record);
       record.type = kGSEventMenuButtonUp;
       GSSendSystemEvent(&record);
    }
```

*UPDATE
What I really need is a generic method like the old one that let me to simulate the pressure of all physical buttons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

[[%c(SBUIController) sharedInstance]clickedMenuButton];

Comment: Thanks It works. But I can't simulate the double tap to call the BackGround app Switcher for example... What a really need is a generic method like the old one that let me to simulate the pressure of all physical buttons

Comment: I think this method only work on UI level, can not simulate hardware level's action. For double tap, you can try this, `[[SBUIController sharedInstance] handleMenuDoubleTap];`

Comment: Yes it works ... I already found that yesterday night.. :) what I miss now is only a method to lock the device ;) have you got some hints ? Thanks

Comment: `[[%c(SBUserAgent) sharedUserAgent] lockAndDimDevice]`

Comment: @guoc, thank you, but how can I simulate volume button click events?

Comment: Hey @Suge, did you find a way to simulate volume button clicks ? I know it's old but we never know 

Answer (score 0):

I found some references to `homeButtonPress` in the header dumps of BiometricKit 
https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers/blob/6e220684809a8e581357c1622efcc002a1df5014/iOS7/PrivateFrameworks/BiometricKit/BiometricKit.h#L68

Comment: Yes, but What I need is a generic method like the old one that let me to simulate the pressure of all physical buttons ;)

Comment: Based on *which* framework this is in, and the name of the method, I would say that this is a **callback** that gets invoked when the home button is pressed.  Not a button that creates a home button press event.