# How to simulate home button press event in iOS 7(Jailbroken)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, tweak

How can I simulate the home button press event in iOS 7? I tried, but it only worked at the home screen but not inside the other apps.The problem is mainly about the `port`, it looks like that if I got the `task port` of `SpringBoard`, it works, otherwise not.But how can I get the `task port` of `SpringBoard` no matter at the home screen or inside others apps?Thank you!

Comment: Might look here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998318/simulate-all-physical-buttons-like-the-pressure-on-the-home-button-on-ios-7-jai

Answer (score 8):

```
[[%c(SBUIController) sharedInstance]clickedMenuButton]; //One tap

[[SBUIController sharedInstance] handleMenuDoubleTap]; //Double tap

[[%c(SBUserAgent) sharedUserAgent] lockAndDimDevice] //Lock button
```

Comment: thank you, but can I simulate home button down and up events separately, and how can I simulate volume button click events?

Comment: @Suge Not that I know of and That's a different question from the initial post. Ask it separately.

Comment: Thank you, may be I can use `IOHIDEventSystem` to achieve this, but can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243657/how-to-get-task-port-of-sbapplication-in-ios-7-jailbroken, I'll very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check these below links:

**1)** http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBApplication

**2)** [Simulate all physical buttons like the pressure on the home button on iOS 7 (Jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998318/simulate-all-physical-buttons-like-the-pressure-on-the-home-button-on-ios-7-jai)

**3)** https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers/blob/6e220684809a8e581357c1622efcc002a1df5014/iOS7/PrivateFrameworks/BiometricKit/BiometricKit.h#L68

Hopefully these links help you in resloving your problem. Cheers :)

Comment: Your second link is nothing  more than what the first answer posted here describes.  Please, don't post redundant information.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nate yes your right, I just add link of that post that it may help Suge to figure out his problem by reading the complete post and discussion there. Thanks